# How to add multiple CA to truststore in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I followed the following tutorial to implement two way SSL authentication: 
http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/

Structure on server: 
**cacerts.jks** has **my_ca** as trusted certificate entry 
**keystore.jks** has **sercer** as Key Pair entry

Browser: 
Has **Client.cer** generated by **my CA** installed in it

If I access the app url, browser now pops my 'Client' certificate to use & I click on cert & click OK, the webpage is displayed.

Now I have an actual ProductionCertificate MyProdCer 
Chain is: **MyProdCer -> IssuerCA -> IntermediateCA-> RootCA**

I have updated cacerts.jks on server to contain IssuerCA, IntermediateCA & RootCA certs along with the original my_ca 
The browser now pops up two options 1. 'Client' cert & 2. 'MyProdCer' 
If I select 1. Client cer then it works as usual, no problem

However if I select 2. 'MyProdCer' then browser displays

```
Certificate-based authentication failed - Error 117 (net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT): Bad SSL client authentication certificate.
```

What am I missing, please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need JKS with all trust ca. With portecle you can edit JKS file. In your tutorial find this "truststoreFile" with Java you can this

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=adminca.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=iofesac123
```